# Google Compute Engine API - Filtering Instances or Other Lists Using Labels / Tags

Tags: google-compute-engine

With the `gcloud` command line tool I can do:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --filter='tags.items:development'
```

The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/list#filter)u[men](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/images/list#filter)t[at](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/networks/list#filter)i[on](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/disks/list#filter) claims: *"..you can also filter on nested fields. For example, you could filter on instances that have set the scheduling.automaticRestart field to true. Use filtering on nested fields to take advantage of labels to organize and search for results based on label values."* But no examples are provided, so it's not clear how one actually goes about this.

I've tried `labels.development eq *.*`, `labels eq *development*`, `labels:development` et al.. I've also tried setting the verbosity of the of the command line client to `info` and looking through the output, as well as monitoring requests that go to the API from the [Compute Engine web console](https://console.cloud.google.com), but neither has gotten me anywhere.

Comment: I found that `gcloud compute instances list --filter='tags.items[0]:yourtagname'` works but only if `yourtagname` is the first tag in the list.

Answer (score 6):

#### Finding Tags with regular expression filters

I'm struggling with the same issue but I think that regular expressions solve the problem.

I have many instances with multiple tags but I can search across all tags with the '~' operator e.g. to find all servers with the production tag:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='tags.items~^production$'
```

For many servers the 'production' tag is the third entry in tags.items yet the regexp finds it.

This seems to work but I can't find any documentation that specifically says that it should work. The nearest is the section on [topic filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) which mentions this

> key ~ value True if key matches the RE (regular expression) pattern
>   value.

**You can also search for multiple tags**

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='tags.items~^production$ AND tags.items~^european$'
```

which would find all servers with the two tags 'production' and 'european'

#### Tags v Custom metadata

If you want something a bit more flexible than tags (which can only be present or missing), you can attach your own **custom multi-valued metadata** to an instance (via the UI, command-line or API). You can then search for particular values of that item.

For example suppose I have different instances supporting eCommerce for different brands, I could attach a custom 'brand' metadata item to each server and then find all of the servers which run my "Coca-Cola" brands via ..

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['brand']['value']='Coca-Cola'"
```

... and my 'Pepsi Cola' servers with ...

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['brand']['value']='Pepsi Cola'"
```

#### Finding Metadata with regular expression filters

You probably guessed this already but the regular expression operator also works with metadata filters so you can do

gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['brand']['value']~'Cola'"

Comment: if you have an `aaaaaproductionbbbbb` tag, it will also match. The solution is to match against `^production$`.

Comment: @snetch - Thanks, I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Do these map to the API? It doesn't seem like the APIs filter expression support anything other than `eq` and `neq`

Comment: @neq Couldn't say I'm afraid - I'm using these from Ansible scripts.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) you can use the following syntax using gcloud cli:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter labels.env=dev
```

Multi Filtering example that I'm using:

```
gcloud compute instances list  --filter="zone:( europe-west1-d )" --filter="name:( testvm )" --filter labels.group=devops --filter labels.environment_type=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Add instance metadata `MyKey=MyValue` for `gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-knbs`:

`gcloud compute instances add-metadata gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-knbs --metadata=MyKey=MyValue`

Display all instances with `MyKey=MyValue`:

`gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['MyKey'][value]='MyValue'"`

Display all instances that belong to the cluster `cluster-asia-east1-a`:

`gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['cluster-name'][value]='cluster-asia-east1-a'"`

```
NAME                                             ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-knbs  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.2   104.155.227.25  RUNNING
gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-x8cv  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.3   104.199.226.16  RUNNING
gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-z5wv  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.4   104.199.134.9   RUNNING
```