# Google Compute Engine API : Instances.list filtering with metadata using REST API

Tags: google-compute-engine

It seems that the method *instances.list* in Compute Engine API doesn't support filtering with metadata in REST.

When using the filter : **metadata.items.key['user'][value]='test-user'**

I get `Invalid value for field 'filter': 'metadata.items.key['user'][value]='test-user''. Invalid list filter expression.`.

However it seems that this is possible using gcloud, see : [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271023/google-compute-engine-api-filtering-instances-or-other-lists-using-labels-ta)

Answer (score 2):

I tested this by first running the gcloud command:

$gcloud compute instances list --filter="metadata.items.key['user']['value']='test-user'"

The gcloud command worked successfully; however, when I tried doing the samething using the API, I received the same error as you.

From researching further, I was able to find this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417346/google-cloud-platform-how-to-filter-instances-list-by-tag) which matches this issue.

There seems to be an internal issue with the Rest API. I would also suggest filing a public issue tracker in regards to this issue. You can submit a public issue tracker by clicking [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877).